# sending username and password via post request in volley in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using this url to send post reqeust via volley:"http://136.243.146.41:8443/api/GetMainCategories".
here is my code:

```
    void MakePostRequest() {
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, mainmenurl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject("{response}");

                        //makemainmenulist();
                        Toast.makeText(Cofeelist.this,"success!--->>>>"+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("sucsses!.....",response);
                        //  value1= jsonResponse.getString("Your ID1");
                      //  value2= jsonResponse.getString("Your ID2");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(Cofeelist.this,"error1!--->>>>"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("Error1!.....",e+"");

                        // banner_id = null;
                       // full_id = null;
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                   Toast.makeText(Cofeelist.this,"error2!--->>>>"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("error2!.....",error+"");

                    // value1= null;
                   // value2= null;
                }
            }
    ) {
        // here is params will add to your url using post method
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", "pourya");
            params.put("key", "54a65sdf4a35s4d");
            return params;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
}
```

but i got this error:"com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.EOFException ".i changed the url to"tarkhinehapp/api/GetMainCategories" but i got another error "  com.android.volley.ServerError"

Comment: post your url  work in browser and check once its working fine or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used volley lib to connect to server and sent username and pass via querystring in url as below:

```
        MyVolleyStringRequest mainmenureq=new MyVolleyStringRequest(Request.Method.GET, G.urlBase+"MainCategoriesApi?username="+"username"+"&"+"key="+"pass",new MyListener(this));
```

the volley made my job so easy!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the server log?